# Is it safe to drop the -webkit vendor prefix from the css3 border-radius yet?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css

I knew that as of some release of Chrome 9 that rounded corners now listen to `border-radius`.

I got curious and tried it on some other browser/OS combinations and found that the following webkit browsers support the non vendor `border-radius`.

- Chrome 9.0.597.98 on windows 7
- Chrome 9.0.597.102 mac osx (snow leopard)
- Safari 5.0.3 on windows 7
- Safari 5.0.3 on mac osx (snow leopard)

With Chrome's automatic background updating in place it's rare for users to be running older versions unless specifically required.

So my question is, is it finally safe to drop the `-webkit` vendor prefix for css3 `border-radius` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I believe it's safe to drop it.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/-moz-border-radius

```
Lowest version for unprefixed "border-radius"
Safari | Chrome | WebKit  
5.0    | 4.0    | 532.5
```

So, it's safe to drop if you don't care about users running older versions of Safari/Chrome.

Not many users are running old versions of Safari/Chrome - these browsers aren't IE, where older versions are sometimes clung to for aeons.

Users running these browsers are often savvy enough to update, and both Safari and Chrome aggressively try to update themselves (Chrome even does it automatically).

Also, http://css3generator.com/ has dropped it. *(the top Google result for "css3 generator")*

Comment: Almost 99% of the Chrome browsers auto update :) So you can guarantee the lowest version at this time is version Chrome 9. There is a graph somewhere online that I can't find it atm

Answer (score 2):

I second Rafal's opinion. Especially iOS 3.x devices should still be around a lot. So it can't harm to give them the -webkit- prefix. Also http://css3please.com/ (the other css3 generator) still includes it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile version of the browser usually are not as up to date as desktop. So it depends who is your audience

Answer (score 0):

iOS 4 still need `webkit` vendor prefix on border-radius

See here http://caniuse.com/#border-radius