# How to write CSS3 rounded corners for IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, rounded-corners

I used to write rounded corners using CSS3 for google Chrome and Safari like this:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

And for FireFox:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

How to write it for IE9?

Comment: You should pay attention to your CSS. If you did, you'd notice the last WebKit property is shorthand for the first four.

Comment: yes, but when i used the shorthand it didn't work on my mac safari

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No vendor prefix needed (this is also supported by Opera):

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

And you can condense your WebKit- and Mozilla-specific styles to these respectively:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
```

As a matter of fact, soon enough you won't need these two properties anymore as the standard `border-radius` is now supported by Safari 5+ and Firefox 4+.

Comment: It's arguably safe to drop the WebKit prefix entirely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137937/is-it-safe-to-drop-the-webkit-vendor-prefix-from-the-css3-border-radius-yet

Comment: yes, but when i used the shorthand it didn't work on my mac safari

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy: You're not using the first version of Safari, are you...? This shorthand version works on Safari 2.0 and later.

Comment: may be I am not sure, don't have the mac now near me, will check it and tell you later the version, but what I know now that it is old mac machine.

Comment: Just a note that if (and you should be, for the time being) you are using the vendor-specific prefixes for mozilla and webkit, then your non-vendor specific code should go *after* those, i.e.:

-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;

Comment: @ iamfriendly, yes this what I am doing but didn't wrote in the sample above.

Comment: @ BoltClock, I found the safari version is 5.0 but may be I wrote it like this for previous version I had, I will edit and check again.

Answer (score 2):

`border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` element is the key for rounded-corners in IE9

Also see: [HTML DOCTYPE Declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: By declaring <!DOCTYPE HTML>, you're telling the browser that your page is to be rendered as 'HTML5.' Many features are dependent on proper declaration.